# ASP.net MVC get users Roles for specific id retrieved from the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, roles

When the user loggedin I wrote this code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(form.username, true);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users",new { id = myUser.userid });
```

Now in the UserController I have this action that retrieve all the data for specific id in the url

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "user")]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
       return View(x.psostTBLs.Where(n => n.post_userid == id).ToList());
    }
```

now  every logged in user can access all other users pages

EXAMPLE: if i logged in as user 100 i can access all other pages in the website and edit their data

localhost:3343/user/100

localhost:3343/user/200

localhost:3343/user/300

in the view  I need something like that:

```
if(i'm logged in as user 100 and i'm in page localhost:3343/user/100)
{
edit
delete
.... etc
}
else if(i'm logged in as user 100 and i'm in page localhost:3343/user/200 or any other page)
{
only I can read the content
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Identity, you can to do in your view like this:

```
 @if(User.IsInRole("canEdit"))
    {
edit
delete
    }
    else
    {
only i can read the content
    }
```

"canEdit" it's the name of role.

Please, read Here :  http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1